# Get any string between 2 string and assign a variable in bash

Tags: bash

I cannot get this to work. I only want to get the string between 2 others in bash. Like this:

```
FOUND=$(echo "If show <start>THIS WORK<end> then it work" | **the magic**)
echo $FOUND
```

It seems so simple...

Comment: Do you have <start> and <end> in your string? Or thats for us as reference? If not then what is your actual string and desired output? A bit more information would certainly help!

Comment: @JaypalSingh the <start> and <end> is a reference. Can be any text :) $FOUND have only to show "THIS WORK"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/.*<start>\(.*\)<end>.*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in bash without any external commands such as awk and sed. When doing a regex match in bash, the results of the match are put into a special array called BASH_REMATCH. The second element of this array contains the match from the first capture group.

```
data="If show <start>THIS WORK<end> then it work"
regex="<start>(.*)<end>"
[[ $data =~ $regex ]] && found="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo $found
```

This can also be done using perl regex in grep (GNU specific):

```
found=$(grep -Po '(?<=<start>).*(?=<end>)' <<< "If show <start>THIS WORK<end> then it work")
echo "$found"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have < start > and < end > in your string then this will work. Set the `FS` to `<` and `>`.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] FOUND=$(echo "If show <start>THIS WORK<end> then it work" | 
awk -v FS="[<>]" '{print $3}')
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo $FOUND
THIS WORK
```