# Get string between strings in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I want to get the string between `<sometag param='` and `'>`

I tried to use the method from [Get any string between 2 string and assign a variable in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568925/get-any-string-between-2-string-and-assign-a-variable-in-bash) to get the "x":

```
 echo "<sometag param='x'><irrelevant stuff='nonsense'>" | tr "'" _ | sed -n 's/.*<sometag param=_\(.*\)_>.*/\1/p'
```

The problem (apart from low efficiency because I just cannot manage to escape the apostrophe correctly for sed) is that sed matches the maximum, i.e. the output is:

```
 x_><irrelevant stuff=_nonsense
```

but the correct output would be the minimum-match, in this example just "x"

Thanks for your help

Comment: For structured data, use a tool which understands the structure. `man xsltproc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
sed -n "s/.*<sometag param='\([^']*\)'>.*/\1/p"
```

Test:

```
echo "<sometag param='x'><irrelevant stuff='nonsense'>" | sed -n "s/.*<sometag param='\([^']*\)'>.*/\1/p"
```

Results:

```
x
```

Explanation:

- Instead of a greedy capture, use a non-greedy capture like: `[^']*`  which means match anything except `'` any number of times. To make the pattern stick, this is followed by: `'>`.
- You can also use double quotes so that you don't need to escape the single quotes. If you wanted to escape the single quotes, you'd do this:

-

```
... | sed -n 's/.*<sometag param='\''\([^'\'']*\)'\''>.*/\1/p'
```

Notice how that the single quotes aren't really escaped. The `sed` expression is stopped, an escaped single quote is inserted and the `sed` expression is re-opened. Think of it like a four character escape sequence.

---

Personally, I'd use `GNU grep`. It would make for a slightly shorter solution. Run like:

```
... | grep -oP "(?<=<sometag param=').*?(?='>)"
```

Test:

```
echo "<sometag param='x'><irrelevant stuff='nonsense'>" | grep -oP "(?<=<sometag param=').*?(?='>)"
```

Results:

```
x
```

Comment: Thanks, the grep-based solution is what I was looking for.

Comment: FYI: The last grep test expression doesn't execute with the grep implementation on OS X 10.11. It may not work on BSDs in general. It DOES work on Ubuntu. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to assemble regexes in those cases, you can just use ' as the field separator

```
in="<sometag param='x'><irrelevant stuff='nonsense'>"

IFS="'" read x whatiwant y <<< "$in"            # bash
echo "$whatiwant"

awk -F\' '{print $2}' <<< "$in"                 # awk
```